# langmap and maps from plugin

Tags: key-bindings

I have set up some langmaps, notably `ü<` and `ó>` on my Hungarian keyboard. I also installed `machakann/vim-swap` which binds `g<` and `g>` to swap arguments in a function. The plugin works with `g<altgr>í` and `g<altgr>y` which is the default way to get these characters on my keyboard, but will not work with `gü` and `gó`. I tried `set langremap` but that didn't help. In fact `gü` actually triggers vim's original `g<`which loads the previous command output.

Any idea on how to get this working properly?

Comment: Try the opposite, `set nolangremap`. I believe the default is on and disabling it might be the sane setting (from my reading of the help docs.)

Comment: hmm, now the default (command output) behaviour doesn't trigger, but neither does what I want :) I guess `langmap` has it's limitation. E.g. I just found out that if I have a `langmap` for `Ő}` moving around the paragraphs work but `fŐ` will not jump as `f}`. This might actually be a good thing, still :)

Comment: I'd still like to understand what is going on, but the workaround for now is explicitly mapping with `nmap gü <Plug>(swap-prev)` and `
nmap gó <Plug>(swap-next)`

Comment: I think this might be a bug... If I use `set langmap=[<` or `set langmap=(<` it works correctly (with `g[` or `g(`, resp.), but `set langmap=é<` and using `gé` doesn't work for me (with a simple `nmap g< gU_` for testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Vim's handling of `'langmap'`. I can consistently reproduce it and it seems to only happen when using a "from" character on the `'langmap'` that is outside of the basic 7-bit ASCII range (letters, numbers, basic symbols.)

I reported the issue upstream here:
https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7458
(I'll update this answer once there's a fix for it.)

For now, as you reported in comments, adding specific mappings seems to be a functioning workaround:

```
nmap gü <Plug>(swap-prev)
nmap gó <Plug>(swap-next)
```

---

In the comments, you also asked about how the `'langmap'` interacts with commands such as `f`, `F`, `t` and `T`. For those, as well as `r` (to replace a single character), the `'langmap'` settings are intentionally not used.

There's a separate `:lmap` command (separate from the `'langmap'` settings) that allow you to create similar mappings to the ones from `'langmap'`, but that work in other situations, which include the `f`, `F`, `t` and `T` motions and the `r` command.

But these also *may* affect the Ex command-line, the line when entering a search pattern (after `/` or `?`) and they may also affect how the key behaves in Insert mode. There's a handful of additional settings to control those, and also key bindings such as `CTRL-^` to switch the behavior in each of those modes. (Warning, the rabbit hole goes deep from here.) See [`:help language-mapping`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#language-mapping) for all the gory details (you'll need to read that carefully and probably experiment with it to find what works well in your case.)

Comment: Thanks! I have a weird feeling of accomplishment that I managed to run into a bug in -vim_ :D Also, that rabbit hole looks a lot deeper than what I'm hoping to gain on first glance, but I'll think on it. (I would not want to mess with insert mode, on the other hand, I usually use vim to type code, which rarely involves writing in Hungarian, so maybe switching could work ...).